# Sanity check answers of minimal polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, irreducible-polynomials

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 27, Exercise B1.

> Find the minimum polynomial of each of the following numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$.
>
> 1. $1 + 2i$
> 2. $1 + \sqrt{2}$
> 3. $1 + \sqrt{2i}$
> 4. $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt[3]{3}}$
> 5. $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$
> 6. $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}$

By minimum polynomial, I think it means polynomials that are monic irreducible.  I think the respective answers are:

1. $x^2-2x+5$
2. $x^2-2x- 1$
3. $(x-1)^4+4$
4. $(x^2-2)^3-3$
5. $\displaystyle(x^2-8)^2-60$
6. $(x^2-1)^2-2$

Correct?

[Corrections]

3. $x^2-4x+5$

Comment: Have you proved irreducibility of all these? Hint:
$$a^4+4=(a^4+4a^2+4)-4a^2$$ is a difference of two squares.

Comment: Well, the hint shows that one of the polynomials in your list is NOT irreducible.

Comment: Right.  $(x-1)^4+4 = [(x-1)^2+2x][(x-1)^2-2x+4] = (x^2+1)(x^2-4x+5)$.

Comment: ok, so this means $x^2-4x+5$ is the minimal polynomial for (3).

Comment: Depends on the meaning of $\sqrt{2i}$. It is ambiguous as a complex number, and the choice affects the minimal polynomial. In other words, whoever gave this exercise mildly effed up. Anyway, $(1+i)^2=2i$ so $\sqrt{2i}=\pm(1+i)$, and the resulting numbers have different minimal polynomials according to the choice of sign.

Comment: Not ruling out the possibility that this was designed to be a trick question. Or, somewhere out of our sight the author describes a definitive choice of branch of complex roots.